# C# Convert.ToString("D2", Dropdownlist value)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, string-formatting, html.dropdownlistfor, string-conversion

Im trying to convert a 
value from the dropdownlist in a View in MVC to string format. The dropdownlist contains the value as "01" but when i try to convert it in to string im getting the value as only "1". I want it as how its exactly showing in the dropdownlist i.e "01". Please find my code below. Help appreciated.

```
NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();

string startHour = Convert.ToString(collection["combostarthour"]);
```

I know that i can later convert it in to 01 by the below code but I want it to do while converting itself in the above code. Thanks

```
string s = startHour.ToString("D2")
```

Comment: why not use `string.Format("D2", collection["combostarthour"]);` ?

Comment: Im trying handle the exception if the NameValueCollection returns null. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as,

```
string startHour = string.Format("{0:D2}", collection["combostarthour"] ?? string.Empty);
```

which will handle null as well.